# Entity Framework making wrong property relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a database with a lot of tables created using code-first. 
3 of the tables are

```
public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual MachineTypeApprovalHist MachineTypeApproval { get; set; }

}

public class MachineTypeApprovalHist 
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; internal set; }
    ...
}

public class MachineTypeApproval
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The weird thing is that EF creates a foreign key from `Machine` to `MachineTypeApproval` (not `MachineTypeApprovalHist` as it should!).
I found out after long time of debugging by looking in the database table directly to see the relations between the tables. The error I got was

The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Machines_dbo.MachineTypeApprovals_MachineTypeApproval_ID". The conflict occurred in database "ATPData", table "dbo.MachineTypeApprovals", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.

The error comes because it tries to use a ID from `MachineTypeApprovalHist` that is not in `MachineTypeApprovals`.

I have tried to rename the property MachineTypeApproval to TypeApproval and making a new migration, but it only renamed the table column and index.

I cannot recreate the database from scratch since I will lose my data, so what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I once had an issue like this and this link helped me out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: are there other navigation properties? AFAIK, for one-to-one relationships EF uses PK=FK relationship and therefore will not create an additional foreign key.

Comment: @OffirPe'er, I read the article from the link, which part helped you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix this, though I feel it should be easier.

The way I did it was to add another property to my `Machine` class to replace the first one.

```
public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual MachineTypeApprovalHist MachineTypeApproval { get; set; }

    //new property
    public virtual MachineTypeApprovalHist TypeApproval {get; set;} 
}
```

then I made a new migration which creates a new columns with foreign key to the correct table.

Now, I couldn't just remove my original property and update the database since I would lose data. So first i removed the original property `MachineTypeApproval` from `Machine` class, then adding a new migration, adding to that migrations Up method the following on the first line before any other call

```
Sql("update [dbo].Machines set TypeApproval_ID = MachineTypeApproval_ID ");
```

In this way the first migration correctly creates the new property, the second migration copies data from the old column to the new, and the second migration removes the old column, and my model and db is now correct.

I just hate that I need two migrations to do this. Also it looks like EF uses the property names BEFORE the property type to determine which table to use, which seems totally crazy to me

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Machine>()
            .HasOptional(_ => _.MachineTypeApproval)
            .WithMany();
    }
}
```

will generate these SQL statements:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Machines] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Machines_dbo.MachineTypeApprovalHists_MachineTypeApproval_ID] FOREIGN KEY([MachineTypeApproval_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MachineTypeApprovalHists] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Machines] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Machines_dbo.MachineTypeApprovalHists_MachineTypeApproval_ID]
GO
```

Comment: Would this not make the navigation property required? It should still remain  nullable/optional.

Comment: tried adding your suggestion to my OnModelCreating, and then creating a new migration, but it only creates empty Up and Down methods

Comment: It means that this foreign key relationship between these tables (Machines and MachineTypeApprovalHists) already exists in the model.

Comment: Can you rename the property MachineTypeApproval to MachineTypeApprovalHist and then creating a new migration?